# "error": "Method Not Allowed", "trace": "org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' not supported

Tags: spring-boot, postman, spring-restcontroller

I am trying to check my `@RestController` with Postman but when I enter `localhost:8081/rest/teachers/remove/2` I gain this error

[image: ERROR]

My `RestController` :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/rest/teachers")
public class TeacherRestController {
private static final String TEACHER_MODEL = "teacher";

@Autowired
TeacherService teacherService;


@DeleteMapping("/remove/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<HttpStatus> deleteTeacher(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
    try {
        teacherService.removeTeacher(teacherService.getTeacherById((int) id));
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is my foolish mistake.
I sent "GET" request on the Postman.
When I switched it to "Delete", it worked.